# Why is the surface area of a sphere equal to $4\pi r^2$

Tags: geometry, 3d, area

I have absolutely no idea where that formula comes from, considering the fact that I am a fifteen year old.
 According to me, one way to think of it is to arrange $4$ circles having radius equal to that of the sphere on it,  but the curvatures are different so that is not possible.
Could someone please explain where the formula comes from?

**Note:** Please remember that I am fifteen years old.
P. S. Let me know if there are any other tags for this question except '3d' .

Comment: I am not well versed with calculus. Just enough to prove to my friends that I am great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a good [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GNcFjFmqEc8) for gaining some intuition.

Comment: I saw the video but the second proof went over my head as it involved calculus($d\theta$ amd stuff), and first proof is fine for me.

Comment: The second proof is mostly left as an exercise while following along with the given hints.